# Is there a worksheet event "BeforeRowDelete"?

Tags: vba, events

Is there a worksheet event "BeforeRowDelete"?
Only the "Worksheet change" event available, but the Range Object "Target" point to the next row of the row I deleted.

Is there any idea to get the row going to be deleted before it actually happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this which I've just knocked together. Enter `RowID` in the last row in column A and if you delete rows/cells that move this cell it will report the last selected range and the row before the range.

```
   Option Explicit

    Dim deletedRng() As Variant

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '***Enter string "RowID" in cell [A1048547]

    Dim rowID As Long
    Dim rowFind As Range

        With Target.Parent

            Set rowFind = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="RowID", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            If rowFind Is Nothing Then
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).Value = "RowID"
            Else
                If rowFind.Row < .Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "Cell (1,1) of range deleted = " & deletedRng(Target.Cells(1, 1).Row, Target.Cells(1, 1).Column)
                    rowFind.ClearContents
                    .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).Value = "RowID"
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        ReDim deletedRng(1, 1)
        deletedRng(1, 1) = Target.Value
     Else
        deletedRng = Target.Parent.Range("A1:" & Target.Address).Value
     End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, I try your code and it do tell me the row number been deleted. but, is it possible to get not only the row number but also the (for example) first cell (`Target.cells(1,1).value`) of the row been deleted?

Comment: Yes - `Target.Cells(1, 1).Address` or for the row `Target.Cells(1, 1).EntireROw.Address`

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I mean I want "Value" of the first cell of the row that has been deleted, not the "Address".

Comment: But `Target.Cells(1, 1).Value` got the next row of the row that deleted. As said is it possible to get the row's first cell's VALUE BEFORE the row been deleted?

Comment: OK - I understand what you want to achieve, I've updated code to show value before deleted of Cells(1,1)

Comment: what I really want is: if there is a "BeforeRowDelete"(or BeforeColumnDelete,BeforeRangeDelete) EVENT, and I can cancel the delete action using the event. But it seems to be impossible.